# Redux-saga: return promises from redux actions

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I am using redux-saga. I want to dispatch an action and use the result of the action immediately after. But the saga dispatches asynchronously and the result is not available right after.

```
class A extends Component{
    handleEvent = (e) =>{
       this.props.getInfo(param);
       //Use Result(this.props.Info) from the action
    }
    render(){
    }
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        Info : state.infoReducer.info
    };
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        getInfo : (val)=>{dispatch(getInfo(val))}          
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) (A);
```

My action creator:

```
export function getInfo(data){
    return{
        type : actionType.GET_INFO,
        payload : data
    }
}
```

The Saga function:

```
function* getInfo(action){
    try {
     const response = yield call(post,Endpoint,param,header);
        const data =  yield response.data;
        if(error) yield put({type: GET_INFO_FAIL});
        else yield put({ type:  GET_INFO_SUCCESS, data });
        
    } catch (e) {
        //
    } 
}
```

The Reducer:

```
const INITIAL_STATE ={
    info : ""
}
const infoReducer=(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionType.GET_INFO_SUCCESS:
        return{
            info : action.data
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create an action creator with promise. Pass the `resolve` and `reject` functions as meta to the action creator. Then call `resolve` and `reject` in worker saga after the API invoking finished.

We can create `bindActionToPromise` helper function to do this.

```js
const bindActionToPromise = (dispatch, actionCreator) => (payload) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => dispatch(actionCreator(payload, { resolve, reject })));
};

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        getInfo: bindActionToPromise(dispatch, getInfo)
    }
}
```

`getInfo` worker saga:

```js
function* getInfoSaga(action) {
  console.log(action);
  const {
    meta: { resolve, reject },
  } = action;
  const response = yield call(apiCall);
  if (response.error) {
    yield put({ type: actionType.GET_INFO_FAIL });
    yield call(reject, response.error);
  } else {
    yield put({ type: actionType.GET_INFO_SUCCESS, data: response.data });
    yield call(resolve, response.data);
  }
}
```

Then, you can get the API response immediately like this:

```js
 this.props.getInfo(param).then(res => console.log(res))
```

An complete, working example:

```js
import { call, put, takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { createStoreWithSaga } from '../../utils';

const actionType = { GET_INFO: 'GET_INFO', GET_INFO_FAIL: 'GET_INFO_FAIL', GET_INFO_SUCCESS: 'GET_INFO_SUCCESS' };

export function getInfo(payload, meta) {
  return {
    type: actionType.GET_INFO,
    payload,
    meta,
  };
}

function apiCall() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve({ data: 'Info from API', error: null });
      //   resolve({ data: null, error: new Error('business error') });
    }, 1000);
  });
}

function* getInfoSaga(action) {
  console.log(action);
  const {
    meta: { resolve, reject },
  } = action;
  const response = yield call(apiCall);
  if (response.error) {
    yield put({ type: actionType.GET_INFO_FAIL });
    yield call(reject, response.error);
  } else {
    yield put({ type: actionType.GET_INFO_SUCCESS, data: response.data });
    yield call(resolve, response.data);
  }
}

function* watchSaga() {
  yield takeLatest(actionType.GET_INFO, getInfoSaga);
}

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  info: '',
};
const infoReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionType.GET_INFO_SUCCESS:
      return {
        info: action.data,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const store = createStoreWithSaga(watchSaga, infoReducer);

export const bindActionToPromise = (dispatch, actionCreator) => (payload) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => dispatch(actionCreator(payload, { resolve, reject })));
};

const boundGetInfo = bindActionToPromise(store.dispatch, getInfo);
boundGetInfo({ id: 1 })
  .then((res) => {
    console.log('res immediately: ', res);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('error immediately: ', err);
  });
store.subscribe(() => {
  console.log('state: ', store.getState());
});
```

Execution output:

```
{
  type: 'GET_INFO',
  payload: { id: 1 },
  meta: { resolve: [Function (anonymous)], reject: [Function (anonymous)] }
}
state:  { info: 'Info from API' }
res immediately:  Info from API
```